# Push notifications not coming using Android 8.1 Oreo using FCM

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, android-8.1-oreo

I am working on FCM push notifications. It is working fine till Android O lesser versions. I have reviewed Android Docs and did Channels in push notifications as well, but problem is that push is not coming in my CustomPushReceiver. For lower versions it is working perfectly fine. My custom push receiver along with manifest codes are given below:

```
public class CustomPushReceiver extends ParsePushBroadcastReceiver {

    int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH;
    private SharedPreferences prefs ;
    Boolean languageBoolean = true;

    public CustomPushReceiver() {
        super();
        Log.e("CustomPushReceiver","Come to this portion");
    }


    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        super.onReceive(context, intent);
        Log.e("onReceive","Come to this portion");
    }

    @Override
    public void onPushReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Log.e("onPushReceive","Come to this portion");
        if (intent == null)
            return;
        try {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(intent.getExtras().getString("com.parse.Data"));
            if (action.equalsIgnoreCase("com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE")) {
                if (json.has("alert"))
                {
                    String message = json.getString("alert");

                    localPushNotifications26GreaterAPI(context, message, json);
                }
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPushDismiss(Context context, Intent intent) {
        super.onPushDismiss(context, intent);
        Log.e("onPushDismiss","Come to this portion");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPushOpen(Context context, Intent intent) {
        super.onPushOpen(context, intent);
        Log.e("onPushOpen","Come to this portion");
    }


    public void localPushNotifications26GreaterAPI(Context context, String message, JSONObject jsonObject){

        Log.e("localPushNoti26API","Come to this portion");

        try {
            if (ParseUser.getCurrentUser() != null) {
                if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {

                    Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

                    // The id of the channel.
                    String id = "my_channel_01";
                    CharSequence name = "com.dcas.responder";
                    String description = "Description";

                    NotificationChannel mChannel = new NotificationChannel(id, name, importance);
                    mChannel.setDescription(description);
                    mChannel.enableLights(true);
                    mChannel.setLightColor(Color.RED);
                    mChannel.enableVibration(true);
                    mChannel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 400, 300, 200, 400});
                    mNotificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel);
                    mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                    int notifyID = 1;
                    String CHANNEL_ID = "my_channel_01";

                String contentTitle = "", contentText ="", messageText ="";
                    if (languageBoolean == true) {
                        contentTitle =  "Dubai Corporation Ambulance Services";
                        contentText  =  "Emergency Request";
                        messageText  =  message;
                    }else{
                        contentTitle =  context.getString(R.string.dubai_corporation_for_ambulance_services);
                        contentText  =  context.getString(R.string.emergency_request);
                        messageText  =  context.getString(R.string.press_here_to_get_medical_help_in_minutes);
                    }

                    Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(context, CHANNEL_ID)
                            .setContentTitle(contentTitle)
                            .setContentText(contentText)
                            .setStyle(new Notification.BigTextStyle().bigText(messageText))
                            .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
                            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.push_icon)
                            .setChannelId(CHANNEL_ID)
                            .build();
                    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

                    mNotificationManager.notify(notifyID, notification);
                } else {
                    localPushNotifications26LowerAPI(context , message);
                }

            }
        }catch(Exception exp){
            exp.getMessage();
        }

    }


    public void localPushNotifications26LowerAPI(Context context, String message){

        Log.e("localPushNotiLowAPI","Come to this portion");

        if (ParseUser.getCurrentUser() != null) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);


            NotificationCompat.Builder b = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);

            String contentTitle = "", contentText ="", messageText ="";
            if (languageBoolean == true) {
                contentTitle =  "Dubai Corporation Ambulance Services";
                contentText  =  "Emergency Request";
                messageText  =  message;
            }else{
                contentTitle =  context.getString(R.string.dubai_corporation_for_ambulance_services);
                contentText  =  context.getString(R.string.emergency_request);
                messageText  =  context.getString(R.string.press_here_to_get_medical_help_in_minutes);
            }

            b.setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
                    .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.push_icon)
                    .setTicker(contentText)
                    .setContentTitle(contentTitle)
                    .setContentText(messageText)
                    .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
                    .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS | Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND)
                    .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
                    .setContentInfo("Info");

            NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

            notificationManager.notify(1, b.build());


        }
    }
}
```

My Manifest file where I am declaring my FCM settings and CustomPushReceiver:

```
<receiver
            android:name="receivers.CustomPushReceiver"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
                <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE" />
                <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver
            android:name="com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
                <category android:name="com.dcas.responder" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <meta-data android:name="com.parse.push.gcm_sender_id"
            android:value="id:5562400#####" />
```

My Application class where I am initializing and subscribing to parse push channel:

```
ParseInstallation installation = ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation();
        installation.put("GCMSenderId", "5562400#####");
        installation.saveInBackground();

ParsePush.subscribeInBackground("dcas" + ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getObjectId(), new SaveCallback() {
                                @Override
                                public void done(ParseException e) {
                                    if(e==null){
                                        Intent intent = new Intent(SplashScreenActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                                        startActivity(intent);
                                        finish();
                                    }
                                }
                            });
```

This is working perfectly fine on Android 27 lower versions and only some times it starts working on Android 27 version too which is very weird without any reason.

Comment: Did you look at documented differences that developers need to pay attention to for moving to android O (probably should consider reading the docs for l-m-n as well) ?